# Metodo Math.Round() não arredonda corretamente

Tags: c#, .net, arredondamento

Estou tendo problemas com o método `Math.Round()` no C#, alguns valores que ele não arredonda corretamente, vou dar alguns exemplos:

```
Math.Round(1190.245, 2)
```

`1190.245` ele deveria arredondar para `1190.25` já que termina com 5 e o 5 aumenta só que ele arredonda para `1190.24`

Outro caso

```
Math.Round(1190.004999999, 2)
```

Ele deveria arredondar para `1190.01` mas arredonda para `1190`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao fórum,poste seu código para facilitar a análise, entretanto, recomendo dar uma passadinha [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para conhecer como as coisas funcionam.

Comment: O código é esse amigo, passo esses valores nesse método e ele retorna errado, somente isso, procuro uma explicação

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx), creio que será o suficiente para você entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: 1190.004999999 arrendondaria para 1190.00 mesmo, o que importa é o 004, não importa o 999999 depois

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem dois problemas no código. O primeiro é que o padrão adotado de arredondamento é esse mesmo. Se quer mudar tem que configurar com a enumeração [`MidpointRounding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Mas neste caso ainda não dará o resultado esperado porque está usando um tipo `double` que não tem exatidão, então no número é um pouco menos do que 1190.245, o que ainda faria arredondar para baixo. Se quer exatidão deve usar um `decimal`.

Aqui mostro que funciona configurando o *midpoint*, desde que o valor seja realmente exato ou um pouco acima, mas ainda não funcionará se ele for um pouco abaixo do que está vendo. E mostro que se usar um decimal funciona no número que deseja.

[Não use tipos com ponto flutuante binário se deseja exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). A maioria dos softwares financeiros que vejo tem esse *bug* causando prejuízos para seus usuários.

O segundo exemplo está com o resultado correto e visível. Mesmo se usar `decimal` e configurar o *midpoint* ainda dará o mesmo resultado. Se quer outras coisa precisa definir um critério e decidir o que fazer, o normal é isso.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(Round(1190.205, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        WriteLine(Round(1190.245M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UZbDKz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DMSaL2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RoundingExactly.cs).